# How to resize width of html table so the last is bigger the first two

Tags: html, css, django

I am new in Django,HTML and CSS and in stackoverflow and need your help.

I have a table:

```
<div class="grade_book"><table class="table">
      <tr><th>Year</th><th>Grade</th><th>Category</th></tr>
   {% for year, grade, category in results %}
           <tr><td>{{year}}</td><td>{{grade}}</td><td>{{category}}</td></tr>        
   {% endfor %} 
        
    </table></div>
```

I want to make **the fisrt two columns width 100px and the third-the last one 250px**.

This is what i tried in **CSS** but it only makes the fisrt column 100 px.

```
  .grade_book table td {text-align: left;font-size: 14px;}

  .grade_book .table{ table-layout:fixed; font-size: 16px; width: 100%;  margin-bottom: 100px; border-collapse: collapse;}

  .grade_book th {  width: 90px;}

  .grade_book th+th {  width: auto;}
```

I really need your help i ma novice in CSS at all . Tried to findsimilar questions but i cannot get the result i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `:nth-child()` selector, with that you can specify which item you want to adjust based on order of appearance.

```
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  .grade_book table td {text-align: left;font-size: 14px;}

  .grade_book .table{ table-layout:fixed; font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 100px; border-collapse: collapse;}

  .grade_book th {  width: 100px}
  .grade_book th:nth-child(3) {  width: 250px;}

 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="grade_book">
  <table class="table">
   <tr><th>Year</th><th>Grade</th><th>Category</th></tr>
   <tr><td>2020</td><td>A</td><td>Science</td></tr>
   <tr><td>2020</td><td>B</td><td>History</td></tr>
   <tr><td>2020</td><td>F</td><td>Math</td></tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You would also need to adjust the `.table` to remove the 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

since the header of your table is hand-written, you can adjust it to this:

```html
<div class="grade_book">
  <table class="table">
    <tr><th width="100">Year</th><th>Grade</th><th width="250">Category</th></tr>
       {% for year, grade, category in results %}
         <tr><td>{{year}}</td><td>{{grade}}</td><td>{{category}}</td></tr>        
       {% endfor %}         
  </table>
</div>
```

Since you hard-set the first and third column, the second one will automatically adjust.
All next rows will also adjust to this.
You will need to remove all the `width` CSS properties

Comment: your code does not work. still gives the first smaller and thenext two bigger

Comment: Sorry Nova, I forgot to mention you should delete all of your CSS width properties, I upated the answer. If this does not work, you might have more CSS files that will meddle with table layout

Answer (score 0):

With using of `:last-child`
I also change the width on your class `.table` to fix the width. otherwise the width wont be respected

I just remove your twig loop but it should work fine :

```css
 .grade_book table td {text-align: left;font-size: 14px;}

  .grade_book .table{ table-layout:fixed; font-size: 16px; width: 450px;  margin-bottom: 100px; border-collapse: collapse;}

  .grade_book th {  width: 100px; padding: 0px;}

  .grade_book th:last-child {  width: 250px;}
```

```html
<div class="grade_book"><table class="table">
      <tr><th>Year</th><th>Grade</th><th>Category</th></tr>
 
           <tr><td>{{year}}</td><td>{{grade}}</td><td>{{category}}</td></tr>        
  
        
    </table></div>
```